# How to replace straight quotation mark (")

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

I would like to replace a straight quotation mark (") using C#.

I might be missing something small, but I can't get it with a normal `string.Replace();`

`someWord.Replace(@""", "&amp;");`

Can I do it with a normal `string.Replace();` or do I need to use `Regex`? If the latter, what would the `Regex` replace look like?

Comment: Although you may want to use the (I think built in) urlencode function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx if that's actually what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I agree with Heinzi, you should use `&quot;` instead of `&amp;`， and `&amp;` means "&"
Btw, after invoking the Replace method, don't forget to set the value to someWord again:

```
someWord = someWord.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
```

And there is another way to do it. Add the reference System.Web, and using System.Web;
then:

someWord = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode（someWord);

Comment: Will this replace all special characters? `(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode（someWord);)`

Comment: @Willem Yes,it will. If you just want to replace the straight quotation mark, don't use it.

Comment: Thats great. Will save me alot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
someWord.Replace("\"", "&amp;");
```

or

```
someWord.Replace(@"""", "&amp;");
```

(Quotes are escaped as `\"` in regular strings and `""` in verbatim strings.)

But you probably meant

```
someWord.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
```

since the HTML entity for straight quotation marks is `&quot;`, not `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
someWord.Replace(@"""", "&amp;");
```

or

```
someWord.Replace("\"", "&amp;");
```